# Do I need to specifically seperate out css and js when using plunker

Tags: javascript, html, css, plunker

This script renders ok on our local webserver but when added to `plunker` nothing is being rendered.

Am I allowed to embed javascript in the html file in plunker - or do I need to explicitly move it to .js files?

To reference another file in plunker do I just supply the file name, like so? ...

```
var pieDataCSV = "pie.csv";
var barDataCSV = "bar.csv";
var lineDataCSV = "line.csv";
```

Here is the plunker I am referring to: https://plnkr.co/edit/QDHVKNxuHAC1TSk1gk4s?p=preview

Comment: f12 console - you have an error - d3 is not defined - you need to reference the https version of the http://d3js.org/d3.v2.js file

Comment: your comment looks more like an answer Pete ... happy to get a friendly comment after a day full of aggressive comments!

Comment: @Pete (and it might be my Birthday ...don't tell any of them) ....that "s" made all the difference : check now ...https://plnkr.co/edit/QDHVKNxuHAC1TSk1gk4s?p=preview. Make an answer from your comment then and this questio/answer will be complete...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your plnkr, you need to change the javascript reference from

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v2.js"></script>
```

to avoid the following error.

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://plnkr.co/edit/QDHVKNxuHAC1TSk1gk4s?p=preview' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://d3js.org/d3.v2.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Comment: thanks but...I know ...Pete told me above in comments above

Comment: @whytheq did it answer your question/solve your problem? If so, it should be an answer. Otherwise it looks like you're question is still unanswered.

Comment: it will be the answer if pete does not answer